# Why JS prototype methods works without .cal() or .apply()?

Tags: javascript, prototype

As I know in JavaScript prototype methods of object needs context so we should call them with `call` or `apply`.

However `Array.prototype` methods works without using `call` or `apply`.

```
Array.prototype.concat(1, 2, 3) // [1,2,3]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Because `Array.prototype` is an empty array. Your call is quite like `[].concat(1, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well context in example is already exist. And it's `Array.prototype`.
As we remember context it's a object before dot:

And your example we can re write like this, and give equal result:

```js
console.log([].concat.call(Array.prototype,[1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it also works when you pass the context to it like

```js
const arr = Array.prototype.concat.call([],1,2,3);
console.log(arr);
```

There is no difference just because `Array.prototype` is the same as `[]`. But if you have an array-like object instead of array and you want to call some array method on it, then you need to use `call` or `bind`.

Probably the most used one is

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
```

which turns `arguments` of the function (which is not a real array) into an array.